# Effect marquee label in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a function for a marquee effect on a label, the label handed it, I put long texts and disable the "AutoSize" property.
The marquee effect is bottom-up, the code that I have is:

```
procedure TForm1.Form_EffectsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak +
    'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text'
    + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak +
    'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text'
    + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak +
    'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text'
    + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak +
    'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text'
    + sLineBreak + 'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak +
    'This is right scrolling text' + sLineBreak;
    test.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.testTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Top := Label1.Top - 10;
  if Label1.Top <= 0 - Label1.Top then
  begin
    Label1.Top := Label1.Height;
  end;
end;
```

Examples :

[image]

[image]

The problem is that it starts and ends badly, begins below normal and ends incomplete because it shows the half and restarts without displaying the other part

What is the problem ?

Comment: Please don't use JPG for screenshots. JPG is only suitable for photographs. Use PNG for screenshots and diagrams (unless SVG is possible).

Comment: https://github.com/tdittmar/delphi-TMarquee with MIT license :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never create animations by moving VCL controls. Instead, draw your animation manually (using the GDI) in the `OnPaint` handler of the form, or of a custom control. If I were you, I'd create a `TMarqueeLabel` descendant of `TCustomControl`.

Anyhow, your logic is strange. `Label1.Top <= 0 - Label1.Top` is equivalent to `Label1.Top <= 0`. Maybe you mean

```
if Label1.Top < -Label1.Height then
  Label1.Top := ClientHeight
```

It is an easy exercise to figure out why this is the desired logic. (This will restart the animation when the entire text has disappeared beyond the top of the screen, and the new animation will start with the text completely hidden below the screen. I am assuming this is what you want.)

Comment: thanks for the help , 
but the plan was to move in the elongated label, not the entire form.

Comment: But you are moving the label, so it is ... moving! Then, even more important that you do this the right way, using a custom control with custom GDI painting. Still, if you insist on doing this the wrong way, you can put the label in a border-less `TPanel` control and replace `Label1.Top := ClientHeight` by `Label1.Top := Panel1.Height`.